# Double setState method in one function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying  to create a autocomplete component. It's an input where user types the countru name and if letters match name of some country, the hints are displayed.
In my App Component i have method `handleChange` Within this method i change my state two times, which is bad idea.
How can I split it to change state in distinct methods ?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import AutoComplete from './autoComplete.jsx';
import data from './data.json';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      inputValue: '',
      resoults: []
    }
  }

  handleChange() {
    let inputValue = this.refs.input.value;
    this.setState({
      inputValue: inputValue
    });

      let regular = "^" + this.state.inputValue;
      let reg = new RegExp(regular , "i");
      let filtered = data.filter((i,index)=> {
      return (reg.test(i.name)
        );
    });
    console.log(filtered);
          this.setState({resoults:filtered})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} type="text" ref="input"/>
        <h3>You typed: {this.state.inputValue}</h3>
        <AutoComplete resoults={this.state.resoults} />
      </div>
      );
  }

}

export default App;

import React, {Component} from 'react';

class AutoComplete extends Component {


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h4>autocompleteComponent</h4>
                {this.props.resoults.map((i)=> {
                    return (
                        <ul>
                            <li>{i.name}</li>
                        </ul>
                    );
                })}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default AutoComplete;
```

Comment: Don't set the `results` on `state`. Instead just filter them in `render` and pass it to `AutoComplete`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found myself in this position many times, but I got to the conclusion that it's better to compute the autocomplete options (in your case) without having them in the state of your component.

As I have used them until now, the state and props of a component should represent minimal data needed to render that specific component. Since you have your input value in the state, having the autocomplete options there also seems redundant to me. So here is what I propose:

```
class App extends Component {
  this.state = {
    inputValue: '',
  };

  handleChange(e) {
    const inputValue = e.target.value;
    this.setState({
      inputValue,
    });
  }

  computeResults() {
    const {inputValue} = this.state;
    // your functionality for computing results here
  }

  render() {
    const {inputValue} = this.state;
    const results = this.computeResults();

    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} value={inputValue} />
        <h2>You typed: {inputValue}</h2>
        <Autocomplete results={results} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

---

### Notes

1. Since your results come synchronously, via the `.json` import, this seems the perfect solution to me. If you want to get them via `fetch` or anything else, then you'll have to figure out a slightly different approach, but keep in mind that the state of your component should not contain redundant data.
2. **Stop using `ref` with `string` value!** and **use `ref`s when there is [absolutely no other way](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#dont-overuse-refs)** because a React component should not generally deal with DOM operations directly. If you really need to use `ref`s, use [`ref` callbacks](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#adding-a-ref-to-a-dom-element).

Hope this helps!

Comment: If you find my answer useful, please accept it as the one for your question!

Comment: This is a much better answer than the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

Use another function and setState callBack:

```
handleChange() {
    let inputValue = this.refs.input.value;
    this.setState(
        {
            inputValue: inputValue
        },
        () => this.secondFunc()
    );
}

secondFunc() {
    let regular = '^' + this.state.inputValue;
    let reg = new RegExp(regular, 'i');
    let filtered = data.filter((i, index) => {
        return reg.test(i.name);
    });
    console.log(filtered);
    this.setState({ resoults: filtered });
}
```

Comment: Note that while this will probably work, it is not the correct approach!